# Are site visitor statistics real or fake?

Tags: discussion, site-metrics

On the right side of Islam SE, I see the statistic:

> 7,637 visitors/day

Are there really that many people who visit daily?

Comment: it seems to be an interesting inquiry, since we are encountering many similar issues regarding that even in other sites statistics. Of course seemingly Islam SE would be counted as a creditable site, then I reckon we can trust it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statistics come from direct measurements of traffic on Islam—Stack Exchange. You can see a slightly different result [via Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/islam.stackexchange.com). It's important to note that [all visitor statistics are estimates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics#Common_sources_of_confusion_in_web_analytics). So you can assume there is some error in that number. But it's likely to be fairly close.

When you write your questions and answers you are potentially helping thousands of other people answer their questions about Islam.

Comment: how does stackexchange make money? and is it governed by any central authority other than the group of users(community)???

Comment: Mostly we make money by selling ads on some of our larger sites and by matching programmers with employers. If you want to learn more, [this podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/02/podcast-62-delete-this-whole-episode/) is a good place to start. Sites are generally self-governed on their own meta. There is a [central meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) for the entire network, but usually questions there related to more than one site. Finally, I'm one of [several Community Managers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/1438) who monitor the sites and help them grow.

Answer (score 1):

In regard to your Inquiry, that you asked “Are there really that many people who visit daily? (7,637 visitors/day)”, according to my ordinary experience concerning the mentioned site and its statistics, it seems to be a correct statistics or at least this would be close to the factual statistics as Mr. Jon Ericson declared as well.

Since it (particularly its main site “stackexchange.com”) would be considered as a relatively a famous site which has pretty a high rank…
Consequently showing such a statistic could be possible. For instance you’d better look at the rank of “stackexchange.com” based on www.alexa.com:

**Global rank: 171**

**Rank in United States: 90**

Reference:

http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/http%3A%2F%2Fislam.stackexchange.com